# Which library should I use to generate RSS in Common Lisp?

Tags: rss, common-lisp

What's the best library to use to generate RSS for a webserver written in Common Lisp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most anything will probably do.  Personally, I've been using xml-emitter for my blog's Atom feed, which has worked out well so far.

Just choose whichever XML generation library you like and hack away, I'd say.  As others have remarked, RSS is simple; it's little work to generate it manually.

That said, I recommend not generating plain strings directly.  Having to deal with quoting data is more of a hassle than installing an XML library, and it's also [insecure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) in case your feed contains data submitted by visitors of your website.

Answer (score 3):

[xml-emitter](http://www.cliki.net/xml-emitter) says it has an RSS 2.0 emitter built in.

Answer (score 3):

CL-WHO can generate XML pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any specific RSS library.  But the format is fairly simple so any library that can write xml will do at that level.

You could have e.g. a look at the nuclblog (http://cyrusharmon.org/projects?project=nuclblog) project as that has the capability to generate an RSS feed for the blog entries it maintains.

Answer (score 1):

[cl-rss-gen](http://www.cliki.net/cl-rss-gen) is a tiny library (LGPL, depends on CL-WHO) that does some boilerplate work for you (supports generating RSS entries directly from CLOS class instances by specifying which slot maps to which attribute).

Take a look at the code before using it, it may give you the idea how it's working and whether you need it or not (as other posters said, you can generate RSS yourself with CL-WHO or any XML generation library).

Oh, and sorry for resurrecting a four years old thread, but if anyone searches for similar library, he/she will find the answer here.